# How can I get the average of a group of items in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, average

I have a table full of districts and a table full of items, their prices, and their district. I want to get the average price for every district that I have and then when I select all the items I want to be able to see the average price of that item district.

My Item Table looks like this:

```
Item Id | Price | District
---------------------------
   1    |   12  | North
   2    |   17  | North
   3    |   9   | East
   4    |   13  | West
   5    |   14  | East
```

And I want it to return after the query:

```
Item ID | District | AVG District Price
--
1       | North    | 14.5
2       | North    | 14.5
3       | East     | 11.5
```

And so on. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't see any evidence of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Are you sure about your expected result?

Comment: @forpas Yes, that is what I want to get. I want to be able to see the average district price for every item.

Comment: @declac . . . If you are selecting all the items, why does the result set have three rows but the sample data five?

Comment: @GordonLinoff As stated in the question I said 'and so on', as my actual table it 3000 values long it was just an example of what I wanted to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, you seem to want a window funtion:

```
select t.*,
       avg(price) over (partition by district) as avg_district_price
from t;
```